# Which version of "common io and common file" of apache poi, we should use for uploading csv file in java 1.4?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, apache-poi

Which version of jars of "common io and common file upload", will be compatible to run in java 1.4, for uploading file to server?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Java 1.4 has been End Of Life for almost 10 years. Don't expect anyone to support it anymore.

Comment: I know but we have environment available of Java 1.4 I have working code of java 1.6 but its not working in 1.4

Comment: "we have environment available of Java 1.4": This environment **must** be updated as soon as possible. Hopefully it is not connected to the Internet anyhow.

Comment: And 1.6, released 12 years ago, was EOL'd in 2013 unless you have Oracle support.  You're not doing much better with 1.6.

Answer (score 2):

Checking the files in the [archive](https://archive.apache.org/dist/commons/io/binaries/), the 1.x versions were compiled with JDK 1.4, so those should work. Some even had target JDK 1.3...

... but also, expect few to no help debugging any trouble you find, as those versions and that JDK have been EOL'ed for several years now.